# Find place near which I passed today in my Timeline in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, geolocation

I have location history/Timeline turned on in Google Maps so my phone records my movements for each day. Today I passed near a restaurant and I want to find it but I don't remember the name. If I just type restaurants it'll show me all the restaurants in the city.

Can I tell Google Maps to highlight any restaurants/ATMs/etc. near which I have passed today?

Answer (score -2):

You can use Google Maps feature Timelines [Google Map Timelines](https://www.google.com/maps/timeline?pb)

Comment: downvoted, please explain why this answer is not useful